# How does wixtoolset v4 use built-in variables in bundle project?

Tags: windows-installer, wix4

I have a wix v4 bundler project and this is content of Bundle.wxs, I expect [ProgramFiles64Folder] can be change to c:\Program Files, but actually it keeps the '[ProgramFiles64Folder]' as is.
I checked the doucment https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/burn/builtin-variables/ , it supports lots of built-in variables, so how can we use the built-in variables in this bundle.wxs file?

```xml
<?include Variables.wxi ?>
<Wix xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal" xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.ManufacturerName)"
          UpgradeCode="39FA01F0CAD240169A99464AD20176DF">
    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="$(var.ResourceDir)License.rtf" LogoFile="Logo.png"
                                              Theme="rtfLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MsiInstaller.TargetDir)Installer.msi" ForcePerMachine="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFiles64Folder]$(var.ManufacturerName)\$(var.ProductName)" />
    <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[InstallFolder]\Installer.exe" />
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

I also trid to use RegistrySearch, it's not working for me either. I would appreciate any suggestions
and also similar code working on wix3, but not working for wix 4.

I make an example on github https://github.com/idiotsky/WixResearch/
In the first commit everything work as expect, but after I change wix project to SDk stytle, it not working any more. I just have a temp solutions use $(env.ProgramW6432)\ replace [ProgramFiles64Folder], but this still does not resolve the issue, due to $(env.ProgramW6432) will use the value on build computer not the install target computer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can help with your registry search issue. First of all you need to go to - manage nuget packages - for the bundle project and install the 'wixtoolset.util' package.

Then at the top of your bundle file add:
'xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"' - in the first wix tag.

then for example use :

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="Installtype"
        Variable="InstallType"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\...\..."
        Value=key
        />
```

Im in the same boat - alot of my wix v3 project stuff no longer works and alot of keywords have changed - documentation seems abit scarce but hope this helped

sorry got the xmlns wrong first time - edited to correct it

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried put the following section, still not working, the full code already update to git hub https://github.com/idiotsky/WixResearch/ , any new suggestion, wix 4 document really sucks, may be they just want to charge the support.
<Fragment>
  <util:RegistrySearch
      Id="ProgramFilesDirSearch"
      Variable="ProgramFilesDirVariable"
      Root="HKLM"
      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
      Value="ProgramFilesDir"
      Result="value" />
</Fragment>

Comment: @FeiXu - strange, looks like you've done the reg search fine, sorry I couldnt help :(  definitely gaps in my knowledge for this - I'll keep looking into tho

Comment: @FeiXu - actually saying that, i've noticed your registry search is in a fragment outside your bundle tag - maybe try putting it within the tag - didn't like it when i just tried it ; but if its not giving you errors maybe im just being pedantic

Comment: if you check my first commit, actually its has a workable solutions when in wix4 beta, when install, if you click options it show [ProgramFiles64Folder], but when install, its working well and install to right place. but this version, need install wix4.exe, this is not available download any more, so I just put it on git too, if you interest it, you can check and install it, thanks. I think they may forget implement this or just by purpose drop this feature.